# Realm and Looper shenanigans

Tags: android, realm, android-looper

I have troubles with Loopers and Realm.

I have an `Activity` that instanciate its `Presenter` in onCreate(), and then call one of its public method `initFirstLaunch()` :

```
RealmChangeListener<CourseDetailed> listener = new RealmChangeListener<CourseDetailed>() {
    @Override
    public void onChange(CourseDetailed element) {
        Log.i("renaud", "courseDetailed.addChangeListener onChange");
        computeTableOfContent(element);
        Log.i("renaud", "1");
        playerViewContract.initWithCourseDetails(element);
        Log.i("renaud", "2");
    }
};

public void initFirstLaunch() {

    courseDetailed = realm.where(CourseDetailed.class).contains("_id", courseId).findFirst();

    if (courseDetailed == null) {
        courseDetailed = realm.createObject(CourseDetailed.class, courseId);
    }

    courseDetailed.addChangeListener(listener);

    Api.getInstance().backend.getCourse(courseId).enqueue(new CustomRetrofitCallBack<CourseDetailed>(playerViewContract) {
        @Override
        public void onResponseReceived(final CourseDetailed response) {

            Realm.getDefaultInstance().executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {
                    realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(response);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

note that `playerViewContract` is my activity in this context.

My problem is that `onChange()` is *sometimes* called, and when it does it blocks my UI Thread (and eventualy provoques a `OutOfMemoryError`). My guess was that I was not in a looper thread, but when I call `Looper.prepare()` anywhere it crashes saying that I'm already in one.

What's happening ?

Thanks

---

Edit : Adding initWithCourseDetailed code

```
@Override
public void initWithCourseDetails(final CourseDetailed detailed) {

    Log.i("renaud", "initWithCourseDetails");

    mDrawer.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            String title = detailed.getName();
            String subtitle = detailed.getCompany().getName();

            if (detailed.getThumbnail() != null) {

                String picUrl = AppConstants.SERVER_URL + "/api/" + detailed.getThumbnail();

                final LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) mNavigationView.findViewById(R.id.layout);
                Picasso.with(ModulePlayerActivity.this)
                        .load(picUrl)
                        .config(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                        .into(new Target() {
                            @Override
                            public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                                l.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap));
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

                            }
                        });
            }

            TextView nameTv = (TextView) mNavigationView.findViewById(R.id.drawer_header_name);
            nameTv.setText(title);

            TextView jobTv = (TextView) mNavigationView.findViewById(R.id.drawer_header_job);
            jobTv.setText(subtitle);

            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();

        }
    });
}
```

---

## Edit : correction

```
Api.getInstance().backend.getCourse(courseId).enqueue(new CustomRetrofitCallBack<CourseDetailed>(playerViewContract) {
            @Override
            public void onResponseReceived(final CourseDetailed response) {

                //TEST
                Realm realm = null;
                try {
                    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
                    realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
                        @Override
                        public void execute(Realm realm) {
                            realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(response);
                        }
                    });
                } finally {
                    if (realm != null) {
                        realm.close();
                    }
                    realm = null;
                }

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UI thread is a Looper thread (it has the looper `Looper.getMainLooper()`), which means it has autoupdate. Auto-update however means that the `ChangeListener` you add to your `RealmObject` will be called whenever the underlying table is modified, and not just once.

(And I should also note that `RealmChangeListener`s are retained with weak reference by Realm's `Context` and so is the `RealmObject`, so [to keep the autoupdate and the change listener intact even through GC, it has to be kept as a field reference](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3359#issuecomment-242994734).

Although it's also worth noting that `findFirst()` can return null if the element is not found by ID, otherwise returns the element immediately.)

So it seems to me that whatever `playerViewContract.initWithCourseDetails(element);` does, it does it again and again and eventually crashes.

I kinda hope I answered your question?

Comment: Things are not clear to me yet. I log the call to `initWithCourseDetails`, and it doesn't pop most of the time, sometimes I see 1 log. I also log the `onChange` call, which is always called once. I understand that it will be called each time my `RealmModel` is updated, that is the behaviour I'm looking for. I don't understand why calling `initWithCourseDetails`makes my model change thought, it's a pure view method. (I add `initWithCourseDetails` code)

Comment: I just got your `RealmChangeListener` point btw, I changed it to be a field of my presenter. Could you just explain me again why you think `onChange` is called infinit times ? And I realize I didn't say thank you for answering me, which is greatly appriciated I assure you

Comment: Well technically if you modify the table only once, then it should be called only once. However if it is called only once, then your code shouldn't crash, unless your `computeTableOfContent(element);` or `initWithCourseDetails` somehow gets stuck in a loop... `createObject()` shouldn't work unless you're in a transaction, so I'm a bit iffy about this code. Can I recommend for you to read my [article](http://medium.com/@Zhuinden/how-to-use-realm-for-android-like-a-champ-and-how-to-tell-if-youre-doing-it-wrong-ac4f66b7f149) on Realm usage?

Comment: Realm is primarily designed for the use-case of downloading data in a background thread, saving it in in the background thread, and showing all results automatically in an auto-updating view ([in my example case, a RecyclerView](https://github.com/Zhuinden/rx-realm-recyclerview-experiment/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/zhuinden/rxrealm/path/dog/DogView.java#L106-L117)). Reactive views, essentially. I'd probably have to see even more of the code to give proper advice.

Comment: Ok, I see there is an underliying conception problem, I'll read your article with attention, try to do what I want, and come back here then. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Very nice article, I changed everythings to match the best practices you've described. The bug were still there but something came up : It is the `courseDetailed.addChangeListener(listener);` that freeze my UI thread ! Even if this listener does absolutly nothing (empty `onChange()`).. I don't know where to look in my code anymore

Comment: Do you by chance use `realm.beginTransaction()` anywhere in your code without either a commit or cancel afterwards?

Comment: Also worth noting that if nothing else works, send your code over to help[at]realm.io and they'll read through it and figure out the cause of the freeze. You're probably getting stuck in some kind of loop.

Comment: Ok I followed your article, replaced all occurence of realm by your way of implementing it ( I was already using realm in a small module). It works fine now ! I don't exactly what was the problem thought

Comment: Oups, talked too soon.. The bug is back, he seems to have its own consciousness

Comment: Is this a private project? I'd have to read through the code to tell you what the problem is.

Comment: I just made a public repo without the gradle properties : https://github.com/renaudfavier/client-android-safe

Comment: The project is being refactored so the structure is pretty cahotic. You're looking for  `com.m360.android.presentation_layer.player.presenter.OnlinePlayerPresenter` and `com.m360.android.presentation_layer.player.view.ModulePlayerActivity`

Comment: Neato! I downloaded it, you should probably delete it though now considering you seem to have shared your keystores (although luckily the passwords not :P). I'll look into it ASAP

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122499/discussion-between-renaud-favier-and-epicpandaforce).

Comment: Sorry I'm answering here and not in chat but i'm on my mobile and it doesn't seem to work. I red your post thank you very much, the notification center is an old and "disabled" part of the code that I didn't think could impact this part, and there was plenty of advice that I'm sure will be very useful to me. I'll be away from civilization for 3 days. I'll give you feedback and update question on Tuesday. Thx again !

Comment: In the meantime, I wrote this article partly for you: https://medium.com/@Zhuinden/basics-of-realm-a-guide-to-using-realm-1-2-0-634471c0fe8f#.kva71ovo1